# What do we mean by bilateral in two-port theory?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have seen two different senses in which we use "bilateral" with respect two-port theory:

(1) From Hayt's *Engineering Circuit Analysis* a network is bilateral under the following:

> Any device for which \$Z_{ij} = Z_{ji}\$ [these are the coefficients of the loop currents under a mesh analysis] is called a bilateral element, and a circuit which contains only bilateral elements is called a bilateral circuit.

Hayt goes on to state

> We have therefore shown that an important property of a bilateral two-port is
> $$y_{12} = y_{21}$$
> [in terms of y-parameters] and this property is glorified by [calling] it as the reciprocity theorem.

As far as I understand it, this reciprocity is both necessary and sufficient for a circuit to be bilateral under Hayt's definition, so we can say that **a circuit is bilateral if and only if \$y_{12} = y_{21}\$ therefor**.

(2) In texts like Gray's *Analysis and Design of Analog Integrated Circuits*, **a circuit is called bilateral if and only if \$y_{12} \neq 0 \$** (and unilateral otherwise).

Are these two definitions the same somehow, or is this just a matter of overloading a word with different definitions?

Answer (score 0):

In every good text on the analysis of electrical networks there is at least one chapter relating to quadripoles. In the case in question we have:

[image]
To understand this further, we make the assumption that all currents and voltages are incremental. That is, more correctly, instead of I1, I2, V1 and V2 one should write: ΔI1, ΔI2, ΔV1, ΔV2 considering all parameters constant. Therefore y11= ΔI1/ΔV1 with V2 constant so ΔV2=0.

Comment: I see. May I ask if you can suggest a fairly rigorous (even grad level) text on the analysis of electrical networks?

Comment: Old book: LINEAR AND NON LINEAR CIRCUITS - Leon O. Chua, Charles Desoer Ernest S. Kuh - McGraw-Hill.  The topic is discussed in chapter X|||.  For other texts search the works of the professor: Chen.